# Why resonant charging produce "no current immediately after discharge"?

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, basic, charging

It's me again, still reading AoE 3rd. On page 40, footnote 35, the author writes:

> Resonant charging is used for the high-voltage supply in flashlamps
>   and stroboscopes, with the advantages of (a) ......, and (b) no
>   current immediately after discharge (see waveforms), thus permitting
>   the flashlamp to “quench” after each flash.

The waveform looks like this:

[image]

So why can resonant charging produce "no current immediately after discharge" but resistive charging doesn't? And I didn't see a current waveform.

Answer (score 3):

Discharge takes the capacitor voltage to zero.

What is the current through resistor R immediately after discharge with Vin across it (hint, Ohms Law, Vin/R)

What is the current through inductor L immediately after discharge with Vin across it (hint, dI/dt = Vin/L, which given that IL was zero prior to discharge, is what immediately after the instant of discharge? Further hint - a finite value for dI/dt means it cannot change in an instant)

Comment: Actually, I don't really know what "discharge" means here. Connecting a resistor or flash lamp or even wire directly across the capacitor?

Comment: So all of a sudden, the voltage across the capacitor becomes 0. Prior to the discharge, the current through L was 0, so at the instant after discharge, it remains 0.

Comment: However, another question: How can the current through R prevent the flashlamp from “quench”ing after each flash? This current should flow through C, and have nothing to do with the load.